# How to change the label color by its id with css?

Tags: html, css

I wonder if there's any possible way to change the `label` property with css according to the string inside its tag. Example I like to change the week day with it's own color : Mon = yellow, Tue = Pink ... Sun = red.

This is the label property toggler. I wish it could have a way of mimic this.

```
input[type=checkbox]:checked + label {
    background:#0099cc;
    border-radius:3px;
    color: #ffffff;
    font-weight:bold;
    padding:0px 3px 0px 3px;
}
```

So, I expect the code to do with the label something like this:

```
input[type=checkbox]:checked + label[id=1] {
    background:#0099cc;
    border-radius:3px;
    color: #ffffff;
    font-weight:bold;
    padding:0px 3px 0px 3px;
}
```

I'm not good at css, please suggest.

Comment: What do you mean? Select a DOM node by it's id? Can we have the HTML?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A couple of important things to remember:

1. The `+` selector in CSS is called the adjacent selector. It selects only the element immediately preceded by the former element. So your label always has to follow the checkbox for it to take effect
2. In CSS, an `id` can not start with a number.

There are many ways you can do this, such as with an id, data attributes, or classes.

Using an id:

```
input[type=checkbox]:checked + label#monday {
}
```

Using a data selector:

```
input[type=checkbox]:checked + label[data-day="monday"] {
}
```

Using a calss:

```
input[type=checkbox]:checked + label.monday {
}
```

Comment: This is what I'm waiting for. Is the `data-day` apply the css to its content inside the `label` tag? From your example, is it apply to `<label>monday</label>`???

Comment: No, that would require the label to have a data attribute called `day` with a value of `monday`. For example, `<label data-day="monday">label text</label>`

Comment: OK, I've got it. So I don't need any further coding to my `label`. I already have `for` in it. Then I have to write the css to apply its property with `input[type=checkbox]:checked + label[for="xxx"]`. Because it always there - the `for` property.

Answer (score 2):

You kind of answered your own question... If the labels have an ID attribute....

```
input[type=checkbox]:checked + label#Monday

<label id="Monday">Monday<label>
```

Comment: Thank you very much, what a stupid me hahaha. I should have think about it before question it here :P

Comment: Ha! ;)  don't forget you don't need to cascade down like that when using id's, just #Monday will do :)

Comment: That's an overly complicated selector. The selector `:checked + #Monday` will do just fine.

Answer (score 1):

Easiest way to do it is assigning an ID to each day (not like you wont need them anyway) and do the following:

```
#id1:checked + label {
  color: red;
}
#id2:checked + label {
  color: blue;
}
#id3:checked + label {
  color: orange;
}
#id4:checked + label {
  color: purple;
}
#id5:checked + label {
  color: green;
}
```

Here is a working [**DEMO**](http://codepen.io/LOTUSMS/pen/oxzzoo)